# Refactoring (Rename) in VS2010 screws up WinForms project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, refactoring

I rename variables local to a specific function, or even variables local to a class, but the built in rename refactoring goes and fixes everything project-wide. I renamed a variable called "d" to "deposits" and it changed every occurrence of "d" in the project, and the only way I noticed it was because date formatting was messed up on a form I hadn't even touched. Besides getting Resharper or another refactoring tool, is there a way to fix VS's refactoring? I did not have the refactoring tools give me trouble on a Silverlight project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you uncheck the "Search in comments" check box when you use this tool. Sometimes the rename command is a bit overzealous updating the comments.

It is unclear from your description, did your rename command erroneously rename unrelated variables with the same name in other classes?

Comment: Yes, I don't think it renamed variables (don't think there was another variabled called "d" that I can think of) but it did go crazy and rename the string "d" EVERYWHERE in the project. It updated 30 different files. Luckily we use TFS so I just compared each file with the checked in version and undid changes on most of the files.

Comment: Now that I think about it, it has renamed variables project-wide when I refactored things like "label1" or "textbox1". When I did this with an SL or class library project I never noticed it exhibiting this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This is not standard Visual Studio functionality, ensure you have no extensions that could be causing this. Also try to reinstall VS.